# Why Ethereum is growing in USD but decreasing in BTC?

Tags: buy-bitcoins, exchange-rate, ethereum

Please explain to me why the ETH/BTC price is decreasing but ETH/USD price is increasing. How does that work? Why it costs less in bitcoins but more in USD? 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the value of btc is increasing at a higher rate than the value of eth.  Therefore it takes less btc to buy eth, and the cost of eth in btc is dropping.

Comment: In other words, consider trading your ETH to BTC if that trend prominently persists.